# looking for views gallery module compatible with lightbox module

Tags: 7, views, javascript, media

I would like to achieve a behaviour like this:

At the bottom of the screen there are thumbnails. Above them is a big image styled for 800x600 which changes after clicking a thumbnail. When the user clicks on the big image, then an overlay with lightbox opens and the image is not 800x600 but full size, scaled to screen. There are working Next and Previous buttons on the lightbox (not necessarily linked to the underlying thumbnails gallery).

How to achieve it? I am interested in a solution working either out of the box or having  clear tweak instructions. Any gallery module and any lightbox will do, as long as they are compatible and have next/previous buttons working.

So far I tested Views Galleriffic and Lightbox2 and Colorbox, using patch from [here](http://drupal.org/node/725128#comment-5837812) and I managed to open the big image in original size using lightbox2 and colorbox. However, Previous and Next buttons are not working in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) with [Views Slideshow Xtra](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_xtra)?

Here are some more details about these modules (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow):

  > ... can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.
- [Views Slideshow Xtra](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_xtra):

  > ... is an enhancement module for Views Slideshow, providing the ability to create overlays for a Views Slideshow. HTML elements are placed in  overlays, with overlay visibility controlled by toggling the CSS display property, so that overlays are displayed with their corresponding slide. Animation of the overlay displays is also supported.

Comment: Thanks, I used just views_slideshow. Because I have also Lightbox2 installed, it shows as a field formatter for the big image, so I don't have to use the xtra. And lightbox prev/next are just working here...